# Helm Upgrade throwing YAML parser errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, yaml, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to run helm upgrade after adding a grafana dashboard, but running into YAML parser errors.
I have no clue what to fix here. Can someone please help in fixing this?

> Error: YAML parse error on grafana/dashboards/elasticsearch-cluster.yaml error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 16: could not find expected ':'

```
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [

     ]
 },
```

Comment: Add the command that generated the error, also add the `grafana/dashboards/elasticsearch-cluster.yaml` file to the question.

Comment: Could you add the full contents to your question pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to indentation,fixed the issue by proper formatting.

Answer (score 3):

A closing curly brace seems to be missing

```
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [

     ]
   } # added this
 },
```